# Bootstrap Vue - table custom field formatter called twice but not working

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a table:

```
<b-table striped hover :items="coursesArray" :fields="fields"></b-table>
```

The data comes from

```
coursesArray: [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "foo",
        teacherEmails: [{ 0: "sample1" }, { 1: "sample2" }, { 2: "sample3" }],
        teacherIds: ["A1", "A2", "A3"],
    },
],
```

And fields are:

```
fields: [
    { key: "id", label: "Course ID" },
    { key: "name", label: "Course Name" },
    {
        key: "teacherEmails",
        label: "Teacher Email",
        formatter: "teacherEmailTCellFormat",
    },
    { key: "teacherIds", label: "Teacher ID" },
],
```

And this is how it's rendered without the formatter.

[image]

So, I added a custom formatter in fields to remove the brackets and curly braces.

The first problem I'm having is that looping over the value to return all the items in `teacherEmails` does not work.

```
teacherEmailTCellFormat(value) {
    console.log(value)
    value.forEach(item => {
        return each[0]
    }
}
```

The second problem, that I don't understand why it's happening, is that if I log the value passed to the formatter, it's clear the formatter function is called twice.

[image]

Any help or clearance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return an array, you can do this using `Array#map`:

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: () => ({
    fields: [
      { key: "id", label: "Course ID" },
      { key: "name", label: "Course Name" },
      { key: "teacherEmails", label: "Teacher Email", formatter: "teacherEmailTCellFormat" },
      { key: "teacherIds", label: "Teacher ID" },
    ],
    coursesArray: [
      {
        id: "1",
        name: "foo",
        teacherEmails: [{ 0: "sample1" }, { 1: "sample2" }, { 2: "sample3" }],
        teacherIds: ["A1", "A2", "A3"],
      }
    ]
  }),
  methods: { 
    teacherEmailTCellFormat(value) {
      return value.map((item, i) => item[i]);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-table striped hover :items="coursesArray" :fields="fields"></b-table>
</div>
```

Note: I assumed the key represents the index of the item in the array, but you can change the mapping as you want. The main issue was returning the array.

Comment: That helped, thank you. Changed the formatter a bit to display it without brackets like this: `let arr = value.map((item, i) => item[i]);
return arr.toString();`

Comment: But, any idea why the formatter is getting called twice? That's Just for curiosity.

Comment: Not sure, it would be something internal using the callback twice.